# locking type 1 initialisation failed

Tags: files

This is Sam. I have been working on a RHEL 5.1.19 virtual machine hosted on my workstation. I accidentally happened to remove a logical volume. Since then i was getting an error "locking type 1 initialisation failed" when i tried running any LVM commands. Could any one please help me rectify this.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

The simple fix is to add --ignorelockingfailure to the vgchange command